# How to use USB drive as remote

Tags: git, usb-drive

I have local copies of a GitHub repo on Laptop and Desktop. The Desktop is ahead of the Laptop and the remote GitHub `origin`. I want to pull changes onto the Laptop, but don't want to push to the public `origin`. How do I set up a USB stick/external HDD as a remote?

Comment: There's an extensive guide in the Git Wikibook: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Git/Repository_on_a_USB_stick

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Plug the USB drive into Desktop, and assuming it's showing up as `J:`

1. Initialise a bare repo that will act as the remote:

   ```
   git init --bare J:\repo_name
   ```
2. `cd` to the local repo and:

   ```
   git remote add usb J:\repo_name
   git checkout master
   git push usb master
   ```

The `master` branch is synced with the `usb` remote. Now plug the USB drive into Laptop, and assuming it's showing up as `D:`

```
git remote add usb D:\repo_name
git checkout master
git pull usb master
```

If you're trying to pull a branch that doesn't exist on Laptop but does on Desktop, you can just do `git checkout the_branch` and it will automatically pull it from `usb` (unless `the_branch` also exists in `origin`, in which case you have to do `git checkout -b the_branch usb\the_branch`)

You might have to `git fetch` if it doesn't find the remote usb branch.

If, later, you plug in the USB drive and it shows up as a different letter, e.g., `K:`, then do:

```
git remote set-url usb K:\repo_name
```

Comment: Or from the USB drive (after `cd D:\ `), just `git pull file:///c:/src` to bypass the remote add step (I had to do this for multiple repos, and thus one less transient step).

Comment: If you are using Git 2.27.0+, you can use `git switch master` instead of `checkout`, which is generally easier and preferred (see [git-switch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch))