# make USB drive work like github - a remote repository

Tags: git, macos, version-control, repository, git-bare

I am working on a project locally on my machine. I want to have an up to date clone on my USB drive so I can hook it up to any other pc, clone it, and will be able to continue working on the project.

I initialised my local copy as a git repo and committed all my files. I then went to my USB drive and created an empty bare repository so this will server as the main remote repo.

What I would like to do next is to populte my USB (remote) repo with my existing project on my local machine. So if I want to go work from a different pc I can use my USB , clone it to the new PC and work from there.

I shall I solve this?

Comment: I think we need to see the error that is thrown when you try to push. Can you add it to the question? (both the command to push and the output).

Comment: @eftshift0 just did. Thanks

Comment: what about this? `git remote -v`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use USB drive as remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569757/how-to-use-usb-drive-as-remote)

Answer (score 0):

Let me understand the problem clearly.
As I understand, you followed this steps:

1. You have your local copy of a project (let's say in `A` folder).
2. Then you initialized it as a git repo (by `git init`)
3. then you committed it in your staging area (through the `commit -m <message>` command) and nothing else in folder `A`, right?
4. Then, you created a new folder (let's call it `B`).
5. You initialized the folder for git (with a new `git init`)
6. Then you tried to clone the repo, right?

If so, I have some questions:

- Which url did you use to make the clone (in step 6)?
- Maybe you forgot to push the repository to a server (between step 3 and 4)
- Let's assume that the previous points were already satisfied, you are trying to push an existing repository into another existing repository, thus it will never work without a merge operation!

If I understand well, you can act in this way by using a git server (e.g., github):

- set a remote url in folder `A` through `git remote add origin <url>`
- push the commit on the remote server (between point 3 and 4) through a
  `git push` operation
- clone the pushed repository on your USB drive (in folder `B`), through a `git clone <url>` operation

Comment: Until step 3. you are correct. I would then like to. have a USB remote repository as the main repo. so If I want to work on another machine I can do so with the USB. So in a way my USB would be my 'github'. Just updated the question to make it clearer

Comment: Ok, now it is clear! You can follow the instructions provided here: [how-to-use-usb-drive-as-remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569757/how-to-use-usb-drive-as-remote)